# IntelliJ 11 hangs when executing grails command

Tags: grails, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 11 with Grails 2.0.0 under Ubuntu. When IntelliJ executes any grails command  it hangs straight away. I am not able to migrate my project to 2.0.0 (from 1.3.7) or even create a new grails project.

No exceptions thrown in the logs, hangs after clicking on create-app using grails.

Anyone have an idea what could be the problem here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, the freeze only occurs when starting idea from a terminal window using & (ampersand for running in background, like this:

```
/path/to/your/ideahome/bin/idea.sh &
```

IDEA then starts correctly, but as soon as any grails command is run, the process enters "stopped" state and the IDEA GUI appears to be frozen.

When doing "fg" on the process, the application wakes up again and actually runs the grails command.

So, the workaround is of course to **not** run IDEA in background, for example by creating a desktop icon using the following as the "command":

```
bash -c "export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/javahome;/path/to/your/ideahome/bin/idea.sh"
```

Comment: This was actually the problem that I was having and not running intellij in backgroud from the command line solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thnx. This solution helped me too. I wonder why IntelliJ team did not address this till now.

Comment: Thank you! It still occurs on IDEA 14

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly my issue. <3

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following to 'unstick' the process though not every time.

when  Intellij hangs due to some grails command or another, I run the following to see which processes are running (I have an alias set with the name 'idea' you would use whatever the command is to run idea)

```
ps -ef | grep idea
```

There are usually 3 or 4 processes, but the first one looks like:

```
username 19349 14977  0 10:41 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/idea
```

I run the following command to kill it

```
kill -9 {processId}
```

For example:

```
kill -9 19349
```

We use `-9` to force full kill the process.

Intellij begins processing as normal. Sometimes I get the prompt about whether I am sure I want to exit to which I reply no.

Sometimes it does not work and I have to kill intelliJ entirely then start over. Most times it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try 11.0.2 RC from http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP. If it doesn't help, file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with a thread dump attached, refer to http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260 for details.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've filled a bug report there - unfortunately no thread dumps as jstack is having a problem to attach to the process.
Hopefully someone will respond to it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-80526